# Layout being altered when non-numeric character is entered into dojo NumberTextBox

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a dialog that is used to set thresholds. I don't want the user to have the ability to enter any non-numeric characters within these so have used the dojo widget 'NumberTextBox'. Problem is that when a non-numeric value is entered in to the textbox, the layout of the combobox is altered. 
[image: layout altered]

Would anyone know what could be wrong? I have tried applying a width to the text boxes, making the table that the boxes sit within wider but nothing is working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Please see code snippet below:

[image]

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle ? Also, it is not very clear what you mean by "altered". Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

When validation fails dijit adds extra classes to the widget's div (dijitTextBoxError, dijitNumberTextBoxError,dijitValidationTextBoxError, dijitError). It's possible that one of these classes has some styles that don't fit with your layout. You can inspect the element with browser tools to find out what styles apply and override them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a problem with your CSS (please add a real sample of you code so we can confirm it).

You can set CSS directly on your DOM forcing style for you `NumberTextBox` element using its property `style`.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mLkfetLp/

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(NumberTextBox){
        new NumberTextBox({
              name: "programmatic",
              style:"width: 50px;", // add your style here!
              constraints: {pattern: "0.######"}
        }, "programmatic").startup();
    });
```